# How to make a concatenated async function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am a nodejs developer and i am used to using dart asynchronous functions in flutter, but it has taken me a little while to understand bringing this way of developing to flutter. I have read that it is a good practice to use asynchronous functions to avoid blocking in applications, for this I have tried to create a function in Flutter but it results in errors:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import '../exception/UnsupportedException.dart';
import '../domain/InfoDTO.dart';

class InfoService {

    static final String INFO_PATH = '/foo';

    Future<List<InfoDTO>> findAll() async {
        final completer = Completer<List<InfoDTO>>();
        final directory = Directory(INFO_PATH);

        directory.exists()
        .then((exists) => {
            if(!exists)
                throw UnsupportedException();
        })
        .then(() => directory.list())
        .then((stream) => stream.map<InfoDTO>((entity) => InfoDTO(entity.path)))
        .then((stream) => stream.toList())
        .then((list) => completer.complete(list));
        
        return completer.future;
    }
}
```

But the compiler says:

> lib/service/info.dart:25:45: Error: Expected '}' before this.
> throw UnsupportedException();
> ^
> lib/service/info.dart:27:15: Error: The argument type 'Stream > Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr > Function(Set)'.
>
> - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
> - 'FileSystemEntity' is from 'dart:io'.
> - 'Set' is from 'dart:core'.
>   .then(() => directory.list())

My idea from nodejs is:

```js
const { Info } = require('../domain');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

module.exports = () => fs
    .readdir('/foo')
    .then(paths => paths.map(path => Info(path)));
```

Can concatenate multiple `then` functions?, can return directly future function from `Directory` like as this?:

```dart
class NetworkService {
    static final String SYS_NET_PATH = '/sys/class/net';

    Future<List<NetworkInterface>> findAllNetworkInterfaces() async {
        return Directory(SYS_NET_PATH).list()
        .then((stream) => stream.map<NetworkInterface>((entity) => NetworkInterface(entity.path, entity.path)))
        .then((stream) => stream.toList());
    }
}
```

And catch any erros from async function like as?:

```dart
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        this.infoService
            .findAll()
            .then((items) => setState((){
                _items = items;
                _loading = false;
            }))
            .catchError((e) => setState((){
                _error = e;
                _loading = false;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: your `findAll()` method is `async` one withot any callbacks so there is no point in dealing with low level `Future` API like `.then` and `Completer`s - instead simply use `await` keyword

Comment: Thanks, but in https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await says `Future<String> createOrderMessage() async {` as example to create async functions D:

Comment: yes, if you have `async` method simply use `await` inside, not `Future.then`

Comment: Then i return the data directly synchronously, if I use await it would not make much sense to use asynchronous functions

Comment: no, you will not return the data synchronously, its the whole idea that code looks as if it was blocked but under the hood `Future` api is used, the link you posted says in its first paragraph: "This codelab teaches you how to write `asynchronous` code using futures and the `async` and `await` keywords."